# Matlab can't read Data from serial port (Warning: Unsuccessful read: The specified amount of data was not returned within the Timeout period..)

Tags: matlab, arduino, timeout, port

I’m trying to get data from the “Kitronyx Snowboard” into Matlab. I’ve got the “Matrix Sensor 1610” connected to the Snowboard which should give 160 bytes of data. Everytime I try to read the Data I get this

> Warning: Unsuccessful read: The specified amount of data was not
>   returned within the Timeout period..

This is my code so far:

```
% setup serial
delete(instrfind);
serialPort = serial('COM5');
command = 'A';
nrow = 16;
ncol = 10;
row_index = [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0];
col_index = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
% 10x16 = 160 bytes
lendata = 160; 
set(serialPort , 'BaudRate', 115200);
set(serialPort,'Terminator','CR') ;
fopen(serialPort);
% Request data
fprintf(serialPort, command);
% Get data
data = fread(serialPort, lendata);
Warning: Unsuccessful read: The specified amount of data was not returned within the Timeout period..
```

I never tried to get data through a port to Matlab before. Can Someone please help? I've tried many timeout periods. No matter how long I'm waiting the result is always the same.

Comment: And according to my device manager COM5 should be the right one

Comment: I assume that you've tried relaunching Matlab and changing the port your device in plugged into? Have you tried a other serial console, e.g., PuTTY? How about if you set `lendata` to a much smaller value like `1` to see if any bytes at all are being returned?

Comment: Thanks for the great advice horchler but I figured it out. My bad. I must have overwritten the firmware preinstalled on the Snowboard. So there was no data coming in. Thanks though.